# Union Types - Allowing different sub types with |

Tags: typescript

I have I type called `Entry` that is:

```
export type Entry = {
  number: number
  position: number
  entryItem: Banana | Orange
}
```

And then I define the entryItem types as:

**Banana type**

```
export type Banana = {
  number: number
  bananaTitle: string
}
```

**Apple type**

```
export type Apple = {
  number: number
  appleTitle: string
}
```

Now, if I do something like:

```
entry.entryItem.bananaTitle
```

I get the error: "Property 'bananaTitle' does not exist on type 'Banana | Apple'"

Similarly, if I do:

```
entry.entryItem.appleTitle
```

I get the error: "Property 'appleTitle' does not exist on type 'Banana | Apple'"

It was my understanding that the operator `|` would allow me to create a type that can "smartly" understand if I am referring to `Banana` or to `Apple` when I do something like `entry.entryItem.UNIQUE_PROPERTY_OF_BANANA_OR_APPLE`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is not a magician. The property `entryItem` might be a `Banana` or an `Apple`. Since we are on the compile-level you have to tell the compiler what the current object is. There are different ways. One of them is to use the `in` operator e.g.

```
function test(entry: Entry) {
  if ("appleTitle" in entry.entryItem) {
     entry.entryItem.appleTitle; // it's an apple
  } else {
    entry.entryItem.bananaTitle; // it's a banana
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two perspectives that need to be taken into account. The code that creates an Entry, and the code that uses an Entry. That type means that if you're you're creating an Entry, then entryItem can freely be a banana or an apple. You have more options than you would have otherwise.

But as for the code that *uses* the Entry, it has less information than it would have had otherwise. You might be dealing with an Apple, or you might be dealing with a Banana. There's no way to tell automatically, so the default behavior is that you can only access properties that are guaranteed to be there. Ie, properties found on both types.

If you want to write code that interacts specifically with apples, or specifically with bananas, then you first need to write code that figures out which one you're dealing with.

One way to do this is to use the `in` operator to see if the property is there:

```
const Example = (entry: Entry) => {
  if ('appleTitle' in entry.entryItem) {
    // Inside this block, typescript knows that item must be an Apple, so you can access things found only on apples.
    console.log(entry.entryItem.appleTitle);
  } else {
    console.log(entry.entryItem.bananaTitle);
  }
}
```

Another option is to change your types into a "[discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)". In other words, have some property which exists on both types, which can uniquely identify what it is we're dealing with. For example:

```
export type Banana = {
  type: 'banana',
  number: number
  bananaTitle: string
}

export type Apple = {
  type: 'apple',
  number: number
  appleTitle: string
}

// then use it like:
const Example = (entry: Entry) => {
  if (entry.entryItem.type === 'apple') {
    // Inside this block, typescript knows that item must be an Apple, so you can access things found only on apples.
    console.log(entry.entryItem.appleTitle);
  } else {
    console.log(entry.entryItem.bananaTitle);
  }
}
```

A third option is to create a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: Thanks! If I go with the `discriminated union` approach by adding a `type`, is it fair to assume that also the backend should change and include this `type`?